# MySQL DateTime Unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, datetime, postman

I have a DATETIME field in my table that is being displayed differently than what I'm returning.

To understand, here are the exact object fields I'm returning in my API:

[image]

However, when I'm using PostMan and looking at the results, the time is being changed from what I'm returning to this:

[image]

I don't understand what's going on. I'm trying to store the DATETIME in the database as UTC time, and then have it sent over to the client, where the client will convert it to local time.

Here's what the DATETIME dates looks like in the database:
[image]

Comment: Looks like your dates come back in UTC time zone. That would explain the difference of 4 hours. And it seems you have an issue in the code between your database and the result. One of the dates could be the current date.

Comment: PostMan is not capable of talking to MySQL directly as MySQL does not speak HTTP/HTTPS protocol. But MySQL does understand queries. What queries are you sending to MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You're not storing the dates in UTC time. "GMT-0400 (EDT)" means that they're being stored in Eastern time. The Z in the other results means UTC (or Zulu) time, according to this spec: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt

I expect that your MySQL installation has the default timezone set to the timezone that your box is in (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) so when you add a time without specifying the timezone, it's assumed it's in the default timezone. That is then being converted to UTC in your response, adding four hours to the time.

You should probably specify a timezone when adding information to the database, and/or change the default timezone for your database. There may also be another layer "helpfully" changing things, depending on the API you're using to access the database, so if there is relevant information about the API, you can add that to your question.